# PHP - Date range by month

Tags: php, arrays, date, date-range, php-carbon

I have a date range and I need it to group by month but I want to keep starting day and ending day. So far I have this:

```
    $interval['from'] = '2017-01-02 00:00:00';
    $interval['to'] = '2017-02-06 23:59:59';

    $start = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $interval['from'])->startOfMonth();
    $end = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $interval['to'])->startOfMonth()->addMonth();
    $separate = CarbonInterval::month();
    $period = new \DatePeriod($start, $separate, $end);

    foreach ($period as $dt) {
        dump($dt);
    }
```

But as result I'm getting:

```
Carbon\Carbon(3) {
   date => "2017-01-01 00:00:00.000000" (26)
   timezone_type => 3
   timezone => "Europe/Prague" (13)
}
Carbon\Carbon(3) {
   date => "2017-02-01 00:00:00.000000" (26)
   timezone_type => 3
   timezone => "Europe/Prague" (13)
}
```

It is grouped by month but I need to get whole month period, I mean from

`2017-01-02 00:00:00` to `2017-01-31 23:59:59`

`2017-02-01 00:00:00` to `2017-02-06 23:59:59`.

**Output:**

```
$array = [
    0 => [
        'from' => '2017-01-02 00:00:00',
        'to' => '2017-01-31 23:59:59'
    ],
    1 => [
        'from' => '2017-02-01 00:00:00',
        'to' => '2017-02-06 23:59:59'
    ]
];
```

What is the easiest way to achive it?

***Edit: Here is a little bit modified Carbon version of accepted answer, maybe somebody will need it:***

```
$interval['from'] = '2017-01-02 00:00:00';
$interval['to'] = '2017-04-08 23:59:59';

$interval_from = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $interval['from']);
$interval_to = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $interval['to']);

$result = [];
foreach (range($interval_from->month, $interval_to->month) as $x) {
    $to = $interval_from->copy()->endOfMonth();

    if ($x == $interval_to->month) {
        $result[] = ["from" => $interval_from, "to" => $interval_to];
    } else {
        $result[] = ["from" => $interval_from, "to" => $to];
    }
    $interval_from = $to->copy()->addSecond();

}
```

Comment: Have a question: After doing `->addMonth()` why does your result that you getting not has `2017-03-01`? Dont know `Carbon`, but is that not a bug in the first place?

Comment: I didn't notice it but if I dump $period variable then I see end date as `2017-03-01` so I think that `CarbonInterval` makes some magic. Anyway is not problem when solution will be in DateTime/DateInterval/DatePeriod class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**PHP code demo**](https://eval.in/774541)

Try this solution you can change from **one month** to **another month**(not year) and then check. Lengthy solution but hopefully works correctly, putting explaination.

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors', 1);

$from=$interval['from'] = '2017-01-02 00:00:00';
$interval['to'] = '2017-03-07 23:59:59';


$month1=date("m",  strtotime($interval['from']));
$month2=date("m",  strtotime($interval['to']));

$result=array();


foreach(range($month1, $month2) as $x)
{
    $dateTimeObj= new DateTime($from);
    $dayDifference=($dateTimeObj->format('d')-1);

    $dateTimeObj= new DateTime($from);
    $dateTimeObj->add(new DateInterval("P1M"));
    $dateTimeObj->sub(new DateInterval("P".$dayDifference."DT1S"));
    $to= $dateTimeObj->format("Y-m-d H:i:s");

    if($x==$month2)
    {
        $dateTimeObj= new DateTime($interval['to']);
        $noOfDays=$dateTimeObj->format("d");
        $dateTimeObj->sub(new DateInterval("P".($noOfDays-1)."D"));
        $from=$dateTimeObj->format("Y-m-d H:i:s");
        $result[]=array("from"=>$from,"to"=>$interval['to']);
    }
    else
    {
        $result[]=array("from"=>$from,"to"=>$to);
    }
    //adding 1 second to $to for next time to be treated as $from
    $dateTimeObj= new DateTime($to);
    $dateTimeObj->add(new DateInterval("PT1S"));
    $from= $dateTimeObj->format("Y-m-d H:i:s");
}
print_r($result);
```

Comment: Thank you, it works. But isn't some modern way to do this (PHP 5.6+)?

Comment: @JaroslavKlimčík Yes you are correct, okay no issues i am adding another solution for this as well.

Comment: @JaroslavKlimčík I followed the same approach but here i am using `DateTime` `DateInterval` inbuild classes of `PHP`.

Comment: No problem, I will convert it to Carbon by myself. It works fine, thank you very much

Comment: @JaroslavKlimčík welcome... and thanks for accepting my answer.